# 2 Bootstrap Datepicker same form

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have two bootstrap datepickers in my form. The datepicker does not close and when i open the second one it overlaps the first one. How could i solve this?
Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input id="beginn" class="datepicker form-control">
<script>
    $(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    });

</script>
</div>

  <div class="col-sm-10">
 <input id="end" class="datepicker form-control">
 <script>
    $(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    });

</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want these controls side-by-side? Clarify what you mean by overlap.

Comment: no. Only one should be open at the same time. The other should be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just delete the first script, because you call `datepicker` plugin to all elements with class `datepicker` twice

```
$(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wbh53gqg/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is fine from what I can tell, but I would use `col-sm-12` instead of `col-sm-10` to make the inputs fullscreen:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <input id="beginn" class="datepicker form-control">
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12">
  <input id="end" class="datepicker form-control">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',    // Or whatever format you want.
      startDate: '2015/01/01'  // Or whatever start date you want.
    });
  });
</script>
```

Using the `document.ready` function, the datepicker control should only initialize once, and you shouldn't have the overlapping issue you have now.

Hope that helps!